# Java SSL Socket Server not correct InputStream

Tags: c#, java, sockets, ssl

Trying to write a Java server <-SSL Socket-> C# client. Faced with the problem that it is impossible to correctly read and write the data in Java from the stream. Only manually. Is there any way to improve reading and writing?

Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Opening server socket...");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    char[] passphrase = "password".toCharArray();
    System.out.println"---------------------");
    System.out.println(java.security.KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    try
    {
        KeyStore keystore1 = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mykeystore.jks");
        keystore1.load(fis, passphrase);
        fis.close();
        KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        FileInputStream fis2 =  new FileInputStream("mykeystore.jks");
        ksTrust.load(fis2, passphrase);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf =    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keystore1, passphrase);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =   TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ksTrust);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = 
        (SSLServerSocketFactory) sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket ss = 
        (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(PORT_WORK);

        while (true) {
            SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ss.accept();
            s.startHandshake();
            s.setTcpNoDelay(true);

            byte[]b = new byte[2048];
            s.getInputStream().read(b);
            System.out.println(new String(b).trim());

            s.getOutputStream().write("Test".getBytes("UTF-8"));

            b = new byte[2048];
            s.getInputStream().read(b);
            System.out.println(new String(b).trim());   

            s.close();
            System.out.println("-------||END||-------");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot open\r\n" + e);
    }
}
```

C#

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
object sender,
X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
    return true;
}    

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient() { SendTimeout = 1000, ReceiveTimeout = 1000 };
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4446);

    client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
    client.NoDelay = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), 
false,ValidateServerCertificate, null);
    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("Test");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            char[] c = new char[2048];
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sslStream);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslStream);
            sw.WriteLine("Hardly one"); sw.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(new string(c, 0, sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length)));
            sw.WriteLine("Simple two"); sw.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e){Console.WriteLine(e.Message);}
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", error.Message);
        if (error.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", error.InnerException.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
    }                                                                        
    client.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by 'impossible' or 'manual', but when reading from a TCP socket in any language it is essential to take notice of the count returned by the read API. You can't assume that it fills the buffer. It's only required to read one or more bytes.